# Update entries of a dictionary in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, parallel-processing

No idea if this is possible, but rather than iterate over a dictionary and modify entries based on some condition, sequentially, I was wondering if it is possible to do this in parallel?

For example, rather than:

```
Dictionary<int, byte> dict = new Dictionary<int, byte>();
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++)
{
    dict[i] = 255;
}
```

I'd like something like:

```
Dictionary<int, byte> dict = new Dictionary<int, byte>();
dict.Parallel(x => x, <condition>, <function_to_apply>);
```

I realise that in order to build the indices for modifying the dict, we would need to iterate and build a list of ints... but I was wondering if there was some sneaky way to do this that would be both faster and more concise than the first example.

I could of course iterate through the `dict` and for each entry, spawn a new thread and run some code, return the value and build a new, updated dictionary, but that seems really overkill.

The reason I'm curious is that the `<function_to_apply>` might be expensive.

Comment: *Don't* do that. Use ConcurrentDictionary if you want a thread-safe collection.

Comment: dictionary is enumerable so it can be used in a Parallel.Foreach loop

Comment: @Boo You should never modify an IEnumerable from different threads.

Comment: BTW *why* update a dictionary in parallel like this? How many entries do you have and why do you assume that updating the dictionary is slow?

Comment: Depending on your scenarion, you could run `<function_to_apply>` in parallel, and then "merge" the results in the main thread.

Comment: @Bigiansen I was thinking about update the value, read it too fast and did not notice values where not created, indeed you should not

Comment: Consider the case, multiple keys in the Dictionary refers to same memory location and updating them in parallel is a race condition, so better use ConcurrentDictionary for thread safe update

Comment: @MrinalKamboj there's no `better`. Dictionary will throw if you try to update it from multiple threads

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos other option would be update inside a lock / mutex, which would work and not throw up AV exception

Comment: @MrinalKamboj At that point just use ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: If you only store *bytes* with an `int` index, a simple array is probably faster *and* uses less memory. A Dictionary calculates int-sized *hashes* for each entry and stores items with the same hash in the same bucket. A hash is Another option could be a `byte` indexed array of `List<int>` that stores the integer values that correspond to the 256 distinct byte values.

Comment: @Bigiansen both are not same, ConcurrentDictionary is convenient but in certain cases an explicit lock for a Dictionary or and Interlock would be faster

Comment: @MrinalKamboj in which case using a *single* thread could be even faster. There's no point in parallel processing if you use *locks*. Remember, parallel doesn't mean *concurrent*

Comment: First calculate all values in parallel, then add\update them in your dictionary, sequentially (now when they are all calculated - it's fast).

Answer (score 4):

> I could of course iterate through the dict and for each entry, spawn a new thread and run some code, return the value and build a new, updated dictionary, but that seems really overkill.

Assuming you don't need the dictionary while it's rebuilt it's not that much:

```
var newDictionary = dictionary.AsParallel()
                              .Select(kvp => 
                                     /* do whatever here as long as
                                       it works with the local kvp variable
                                       and not the original dict */
                                     new
                                     {
                                          Key = kvp.Key,
                                          NewValue = function_to_apply(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
                                     })
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                                                   x => x.NewValue);
```

Then lock whatever sync object you need and swap the new and old dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I mostly agree with others recommending `ConcurrentDictionary<>` - it is designed to be thread-safe.

But **if you are adventurous coder ;)** and performance it super-critical for you, you could sometimes try doing what you (I suppose) is trying to do **in case no new keys are added and no keys are removed** from dictionary during your parallel manipulations:

```
int keysNumber = 1000000;
Dictionary<int, string> d = Enumerable.Range(1, keysNumber)
                                .ToDictionary(x => x, x => (string)null);

Parallel.For(1, keysNumber + 1, k => { d[k] = "Value" + k; /*Some complex logic might go here*/ });
```

To verify data consistency after these operations you can add:

```
Debug.Assert(d.Count == keysNumber);
for (int i = 1; i <= keysNumber; i++)
{
    Debug.Assert(d[i] == "Value" + i);
}
Console.WriteLine("Successful");
```

**WHY IT WORKS:**

Basically we have created dictionary in advance from SINGLE main thread and then popullated it in parallel. What allows us to do that is that current Dictionary implementation (Microsoft does not guarantee that, but most likely won't ever change) defines it's structure solely on keys, and values are just assigned to corresponding cells. Since each key is being assigned a new value from single thread we do not have race condition, and since navigating the hashtable concurrently does not alter it, everything works fine.

But you should be really careful with such code and have very good reasons not to use `ConcurrentDictionary`.

**PS:** My main idea is not even a "hack" of using Dicrionary concurrently, but to draw attention that not always every data structure need to be concurrent. I saw `ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentStack<...>>`, while each stack object in dictionary could be accessed only from single thread and that is an overkill and doesn't make your performance better. Just keep in mind what are you affecting and what can go wrong with multithreading scenarios.

Comment: You can surely access keys in parallel, but problem would be then value is not an immutable type, its better to create a local value and then assign to the key as in the answer by @nvoigt

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, I agree, but it's mostly other topic, not specifically  related to Dicrionary and nobody here mentioned which value type does OP use.

Comment: *"current Dictionary implementation [...] but most likely won't ever change"* -- What is the current implementation? The implementation of .NET Core 2.1? The implementation of .NET Framework 4.7.1? Have you verified that your code is safe on all previous and subsequent .NET versions and platforms? I am not a fan of hacks like that, because I don't want to impose on myself the obligation to scrutinize the source code of each and every MS .NET runtime version, in order to assert the correctness of my code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, all those versions of .NET have exactly the same behavior regarding my 5-year-old comment: "in case no new keys are added and no keys are removed from dictionary during your parallel manipulations" (and of course, different threads should manipulate on values of different keys) - you should be fine.
Moreover, I cannot imagine ANY implementation of a hash table, which wouldn't be thread-safe under those circumstances. This is easy to prove: if hash-table structure was dependent on values, - you wouldn't be able to identify location by key, - so it's not, and can never be.

Comment: There are numerous benchmarks showing ConcurrentDictionary<> being ~5-10 times slower than Dictionary<> (and similar magnitude on memory consumption difference). If performance isn't too critical (which is the case for 99% of projects), - with no hesitation go with ConcurrentDictionary! But if you cannot have such a luxury, - you have to be creative and understand what you are doing really well.